# Some compilations appear in a different location

Tags: itunes

I'm an amateur DJ who uses iTunes as my playback software for live shows (because gapless playback is a must for some things) as well as for my own personal use. Primarily, I mix Monstercat music, though some times I get special requests for different things and they get mixed in.

I had been using iTunes 12.4 for a while, but it kept nagging me to update, so I updated to 12.6 (build 100), and I noticed something strange.

Monstercat releases numbered albums, starting at 001 and making it up (so far) to 030. I don't have all of these loaded into iTunes, but for some reason, I opened up iTunes to find some of the albums were not where they usually were.

Albums 005 through 029 are sorted under "normal" albums while the rest (001 through 004) appear to have been sorted separately under a new "Compilations" category.

I would like these albums displayed together in the same place, however I cannot find any reason why some would appear in one location and others in another. Below is a cross-examination of two of the albums, 001 showing up in the Compilations section and 005 showing up in the normal Albums section. As you can see below, the albums (for the points that matter), are functionally identical. From my research, these points include `Album`, `Album Artist`, `Sort Album`, and `Sort Artist`.

Additionally, note how Monstercat 005 (which is sorted as a "normal" album) shows its album art in the top left of the information screen, while Monstercat 001 (which is sorted as a compilation album) does not.

What is causing the albums to be sorted differently and what can I do to make them appear in the same space? I don't care if they show up under Compilations or under normal albums.

Edit: As per @Monomeeth's suggestion, I have added an image showing the other requested tabs.

Additionally, I've poked around at other albums in the Compilations category and it seems that while 001 and 002 are missing the album art on the edit modal, it is present on 003, 004, and several other albums.

Thank you,

Fox

[image: iTunes Albums Comparison]
[image: Options and Artwork tabs]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) You've shown us the Details and Sorting tabs, but can I suggest you edit your question to include screenshots of the Options and File tabs (if present)? Also, in relation to the Artwork tab, can you advise whether there is in fact artwork shown in all cases?

Comment: @Monomeeth I've added the requested information. Let me know if there's anything else you need. I'll have to link it in a comment though because SE only allows two links until you have a 10+ reputation.

Comment: If it's relevant, here's a picture of the file tab of one of the songs: [https://imgur.com/a/MOAya](https://imgur.com/a/MOAya). Note that all of the Monstercat albums in iTunes are `aiff` files.